# outerWidth without jquery

Tags: javascript

It's possible to get the element outerWidth using the dom?

Ej:

```
var width = document.getElementById('myDiv').outerWidth;
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, but you can get offsetWidth, which is probably what you want.

From http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

**offsetWidth** and **offsetHeight**

> The width & height of the entire element, including **borders** and
>   **padding** (excluding *margins*).

**clientWidth** and **clientHeight**

> The width & height of the element including **padding** (excluding
>   *borders* and *margins*)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvRAm/15/) for an example.

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('div');

document.body.innerHTML += `
  clientWidth: ${elm.clientWidth} px
  <br>
  scrollWidth: ${elm.scrollWidth} px
  <br>
  offsetWidth: ${elm.offsetWidth} px`
```

```css
div{
  width      : 200px;
  padding    : 10px;
  border     : 10px solid gold;
  
  margin     : 10px;
  background : lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you use jQuery you have more options: width, innerWidth and outerWidth properties. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/

Comment: It should be noted, that they aren't *exactly* the same. jQuery will give you the width of the element even if it isn't in the document, or if it is hidden; whereas `element.outerWidth` and `element.clientWidth` will return `0` if the element is hidden, and `undefined` if it is not in the document.

Comment: offsetWidth is not crossbrowser

Comment: seems like you should use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` as it is available in browsers other than Chrome (unlike `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`). it returns an object with `width` and `height` properties.

Answer (score 7):

Sean provided the perfect solution for outerWidth().

Just to add to that, if you're looking for a substitution for any or all of the jQuery dimension getters related to width, see my solution below.

**Note:** this also provides the correct dimensions even with `* { box-sizing: border-box }`

```
function getWidth(el, type) {
  if (type === 'inner') // .innerWidth()
    return el.clientWidth;
  else if (type === 'outer') // .outerWidth()
    return el.offsetWidth;
  let s = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
  if (type === 'width') // .width()
    return el.clientWidth - parseInt(s.getPropertyValue('padding-left')) - parseInt(s.getPropertyValue('padding-right'));
  else if (type === 'full') // .outerWidth(includeMargins = true)
    return el.offsetWidth + parseInt(s.getPropertyValue('margin-left')) + parseInt(s.getPropertyValue('margin-right'));
  return null;
}
```