# outerWidth and outerHeight not working

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me please, why is this not working? It gives me the "undefined" value instead of true one.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var w = document.getElementById("try").outerWidth;
  var h = document.getElementById("try").outerHeight;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="try">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Or either: [Full height of a html element (div) including border, padding and margin?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10787782/3132718)

Comment: The outerWitdh is jQuery not a native javascript function. [Look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195402/outerwidth-without-jquery)

Comment: but why then `window.outerWidth;` works?

Comment: @harriet because only the window object has these properties.

Comment: hmmm... ok then, thanks guys!