# Get offset right in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the offset of an element from the right side, relative to the `window`?

I can only find jQuery solutions but I need a solution using vanilla JavaScript.

This is the solution using jQuery

```
var rt = ($(window).width() - ($whatever.offset().left + $whatever.outerWidth()));
```

How do I translate this to vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: [you might not need jquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz OP isn't asking for jQuery, they are using jQuery as an example and asking how to do it natively

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz How is this relevant? He's asking for vanilla javascript solution not jQuery.

Comment: @PatrickEvans The link shows implementation of jquery funcion as `offset()` and `width()` in vanillaJS. He could just port his current solution using jquery to vanillaJS using these examples

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz If that's right, then putting "you might not need jquery" as a comment is not really reflecting the intentions, does it.

Comment: @Adriani6 , I think that the comment from Luis is ok...it's like a RTFM kind of comment.

Comment: @Adriani6 that is the name of the page

Comment: True guys, but that still is not what the intentions are. I would rather have a comment with "RTFM" than opposite of what the question is, that's personal preference though. Not being salty or anything, don't take it personally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try using [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to achieve that behavior. If you wrote your code to use this instead of jQuery, it would look something like:

```
var rt = window.innerWidth - element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
```

Comment: Thanks, exacly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

- You can get the width of an element using `.innerWidth`
- You can get the offset values of a element using `getBoundingClientRect()`
- You can get the outerWidth using `offsetWidth`

Porting your solution would be something like this:

```
window.innerWidth - (element.getBoundingClientRect().left + element.offsetWidth)
```

---

For more info you can check [this link](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the offset left position using the .offsetLeft attribute on an element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

For outer width see this answer:
[outerWidth without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195402/outerwidth-without-jquery)

So it would be written something like:

```
var rt = function() {
  var someElement = document.getElementById('someID');
  return window.innerWidth - (someElement.offsetLeft + someElement.offsetWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the window size and subtract the x offset plus the width of the element you want to get the offset for.

```
function windowOffsetRight (ele) { 
    let rect = ele.getBoundingClientRect (); 
    let width = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    return  width - ( rect.x + rect.width)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to translate the jQuery functions in vanilla JS.

```
$window() // jQuery
window // Vanilla JS

$whatever // jQuery (probably a variable of $('.whatever'))
document.querySelectorAll('.whatever') // Vanilla JS

offset().left // jQuery
offsetLeft // Vanilla JS

outerWidth() // jQuery
offsetWidth // Vanilla JS
```

```js
const el =  document.getElementById('test');
console.log(window.innerWidth - (el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth));
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Of course there are many other ways how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers returned the correct value in my case, if there was scrolling involved. Here's what did the trick in my case:

```
var clientRect = document.querySelector("#element").getBoundingClientRect();
var offset = { 
    top: clientRect.top + window.scrollY, 
    left: clientRect.left + window.scrollX, 
};

console.log(offset);
```